# i want to show value arraylist in arraylist javaspring, how to fix it?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, arraylist

**My code**

```
public List<PaymentDetailInfo> PaymentDetailsInfo(List<Transaction> transactionInfo) {
    List<PaymentDetailInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
    PaymentDetailInfo pay = new PaymentDetailInfo();
    List<PaymentDetailProduct> detProd = new ArrayList<>();
    PaymentDetailProduct det = new PaymentDetailProduct();

    for (int i = 0; i < transactionInfo.size(); i++) {
        pay.setTransactionId(transactionInfo.get(i).getTransactionId());
        pay.setYourPayment(transactionInfo.get(i).getYourPayment() == null ? 0 : transactionInfo.get(i).getYourPayment());
        pay.setSisaPembayaran(transactionInfo.get(i).getSisaPembayaran() == null ? 0 : transactionInfo.get(i).getSisaPembayaran());
        pay.setDendaKeterlambatan(transactionInfo.get(i).getDendaKeterlambatan() == null ? 0 : transactionInfo.get(i).getDendaKeterlambatan());
        pay.setJatuhTempo(transactionInfo.get(i).getJatuhTempo() == null ? "" : transactionInfo.get(i).getJatuhTempo());
        pay.setTotalPembayaran(transactionInfo.get(i).getTotalPembayaran() == null ? 0 : transactionInfo.get(i).getTotalPembayaran());
        for(int j = 0; j<transactionInfo.get(i).getMerchantProduct().size(); j++){
            det.setProductId(transactionInfo.get(i).getMerchantProduct().iterator().next().getMerchantProductId());
            det.setProductName(transactionInfo.get(i).getMerchantProduct().iterator().next().getProductName());
            det.setProductPrice(transactionInfo.get(i).getMerchantProduct().iterator().next().getProductPrice());
            det.setRegisteredDate(transactionInfo.get(i).getMerchantProduct().iterator().next().getCreatedDate());
            det.setLastModified(transactionInfo.get(i).getMerchantProduct().iterator().next().getUpdatedDate());
            detProd.add(det);
            pay.setPaymentProduct(detProd);
        }
        
        pay.setRegisteredDate(DateUtils.formatDateTimeOrEmptyString(transactionInfo.get(i).getCreatedDate()));
        pay.setLastModified(DateUtils.formatDateTimeOrEmptyString(transactionInfo.get(i).getUpdatedDate()));
        
        
        result.add(pay);
    }
    return result;
}
```

{
"meta": {
"code": "2000",
"message": "Sukses"
},
"data": {
"detailPayment": {
"fin_payment": {
"financialName": "BCAFINANCE",
"loanLimit": 10000000,
"sisaLimit": 7900000,
"loanId": "61929149-59f4-4f2e-9ffd-7bbc6370fdaf",
"registeredDate": "06/01/2021 22:20",
"lastModified": "07/Jan/2021 03:03"
},
"det_payment": [
{
"transactionId": "09699913-e006-4684-b1e3-a346991609bd",
"yourPayment": 0,
"sisaPembayaran": 0,
"dendaKeterlambatan": 0,
"jatuhTempo": "",
"paymentProduct": [
{
"productId": "39c3cfdb-5e76-45c3-b0a1-d96d0181a73c",
"productName": "BAJU",
"productPrice": 350000,
"registeredDate": "2021-01-06T22:50:41.270955"
},
{
"productId": "39c3cfdb-5e76-45c3-b0a1-d96d0181a73c",
"productName": "BAJU",
"productPrice": 350000,
"registeredDate": "2021-01-06T22:50:41.270955"
},
{
"productId": "39c3cfdb-5e76-45c3-b0a1-d96d0181a73c",
"productName": "BAJU",
"productPrice": 350000,
"registeredDate": "2021-01-06T22:50:41.270955"
},
{
"productId": "39c3cfdb-5e76-45c3-b0a1-d96d0181a73c",
"productName": "BAJU",
"productPrice": 350000,
"registeredDate": "2021-01-06T22:50:41.270955"
},
{
"productId": "39c3cfdb-5e76-45c3-b0a1-d96d0181a73c",
"productName": "BAJU",
"productPrice": 350000,
"registeredDate": "2021-01-06T22:50:41.270955"
}
],
"totalPembayaran": 0,
"registeredDate": "",
"lastModified": ""
},
{
"transactionId": "09699913-e006-4684-b1e3-a346991609bd",
"yourPayment": 0,
"sisaPembayaran": 0,
"dendaKeterlambatan": 0,
"j

Comment: value of what specifically?

Comment: i want to response paymentProduct to looping value, not like a response.